Updating all files with a template not working (PHP)
My code below is attempting to update a bunch of chat servers in the directory /c/sl/*. I have two files in there, and both of them have a $_SESSION variable with server infromation. Now, I'm trying to use the template to update it to all the files in /c/sl/ and still have the server infromation as the one in the template is blank.
$directory = "/c/sl/*";
  $files = glob($directory);
  print_r($files);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
      $content = file_get_contents($file);
      preg_match('/\$_SESSION\["server"\] = "(.*?)";/', $content, $matches_server);
      preg_match('/\$_SESSION\["serverName"\] = "(.*?)";/', $content, $matches_serverName);

      $template = file_get_contents("template.php");
      $template = preg_replace('/\$_SESSION\["server"\] = "(.*?)";/', '$_SESSION["server"] = "' . $matches_server[1] . '";', $template);
      $template = preg_replace('/\$_SESSION\["serverName"\] = "(.*?)";/', '$_SESSION["serverName"] = "' . $matches_serverName[1] . '";', $template);
      file_put_contents("/c/sl/" . $file . ".php", $template);

      echo "Template updated for " . $matches_server[1] . " with " . $matches_serverName[1] . "<br>";
  }
  echo "Variables updated successfully!";

However, when my code tries to get the files, the array comes up as blank, no files are updated. Any help? I can't seem to get the glob function to work, the array of the files always comes up as blank: Array ( )
Also, the "Variables updated successfully" comes up.

Try $files = glob($directory, GLOB_ERR); to see if there's any errors

Got this error: Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given in /home/runner/Imulat-Beta/cr.php on line 74

That means that glob() is getting an error. The value of $directory is probably wrong.

Are you sure the c directory is in the root folder rather than your home directory?

If you use ls /c/sl do you see the files?

You probably shouldn't put the output files in the same directory as the input files. The next time you run the script, the output files will be included in the glob() results.

Which array? Where is your sample data?

Thanks to Chris Haas, I edited the glob function to: glob($directory, GLOB_ERR);. It came up with this error: Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given in /home/runner/Imulat-Beta/cr.php on line 74

This answer was posted as an edit to the question Updating all files with a template not working (PHP) (fixed) by the OP Rosake under CC BY-SA 4.0.
